# Java abstract class constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I'm wondering what is happening here:

I have abstract superclass

```
public abstract class Superclass {
  public Superclass()
  {
        doSth();
  }
  public abstract void doSth();
}
```

And subclass

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass{
   private int x = 10;
   public void doSth()
   {
      System.out.println("Value x="+this.x);        
   }    
}
```

When I make

```
Subclass x= new Subclass();
x.doSth();
```

I get:

```
Value x=0
Value x=10
```

I don't know why first I get x=0 (why not x=10 from the start?) and then x=10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constructor of the super-class is executed before the isntance initializer expressions of the sub-class, which is why `x` still has the default value of 0 in the first call to `doSth()`. The second call `x.doSth()` takes places after the `Subclass` instance is fully initialized, so `x` contains `10`.

More details :

When you call the constrcutor of `Subclass`, first it calls the constructor of `Superclass` which calls the constructor of `Object`. Then the body of the `Superclass` constructor is executed, so `doSth()` is executed. Only after the `Superclass` constructor is done, the instance initialization expressions of `Subclass` (in your case, the assignment `x = 10;` are evaluated. Before they are evaluated, `x` still contains the default value - 0, which is the value you see printed by the first call to `doSth()`.